# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, quartz-scheduler

I've developed some code that executes a quartz job.At first the code was outside the tomcat and it executes very well, but when I tried to embed the same code inside a web application I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.
I'm using quartz 2.1.5 and it's already in the class path.
Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
        at org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl.isConcurrentExectionDisallowed(JobDetailImpl.java:390)
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RAMJobStore.java:1447)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1273)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl.isConcurrentExectionDisallowed(JobDetailImpl.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RAMJobStore.java:1447)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
```

Comment: Hey @Mohamed I'm using quartz-1.6.0.jar and I'm not problem :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have only 1 quartz-all-.jar in your classpath (maybe you have 2 : 1 in Tomcat lib folder + 1 in your war)

Comment: In my case i was using dumb IDE netbeans when i deploy it stops tomcat and starts it again the deploy it again so i get that exception, try clean build and see if the exception gose

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError`s point to a missing JAR or class on the classpath. In this case the problem is likely that in Tomcat you have `quartz-<ver>.jar` on your classpath when you actually need `quartz-all-<ver>.jar`.

Comment: After I substituted the quartz-<ver>.jar with quartz-all-<ver>.jar, I'm getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

for them who use maven can use the new version by add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **keep the .jar file inside of the project location**. Import .jar file from the **outside from the location which the project have is the reason for getting this error**. also verified that if the project is a maven project, then it should include the maven dependency in the pom.xml to add the dependency to the project

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
   <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org</groupId>
   <artifactId>quartz_job</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```